# HTML encoded letters in XSL-FO

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using XSLT to transform XML to XSL-FO and then create PDF from it (using [Apache FOP](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)). Unfortunately I have HTML encoded letters in XML like:

```
<TAG>wp&#322;yw</TAG>
```

How can I have `Ł` instead of `&#322;` in my output PDF?

Comment: Maybe this can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956218/xsl-fo-foreign-characters-polish-unicode-in-apache-fop-v-1-1

Comment: It seems to work properly. What is the Font face you want to use (Arial, Helvetica, ...)? Have you check it is installed on your computer?

Comment: @potame I tried both Arial and Times. They are both installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that configuration of FOP is not properly set. Edit or duplicate the file `fop.xconf` that you will find in the `conf` folder within your FOP installation directory.

In this file, locate the `<renderer mime="application/pdf">` tag. Inside the `<fonts>` child tag, add `<auto-detect/>`.
You should obtains a `<renderer>` configuration like this (I have removed all the commented text):

```
<renderer mime="application/pdf">
  <filterList>
    <!-- provides compression using zlib flate (default is on) -->
    <value>flate</value>

    <!-- encodes binary data into printable ascii characters (default off)
         This provides about a 4:5 expansion of data size -->
    <!-- <value>ascii-85</value> -->

    <!-- encodes binary data with hex representation (default off)
         This filter is not recommended as it doubles the data size -->
    <!-- <value>ascii-hex</value> -->
  </filterList>

  <fonts>
    <!-- ... lots of commented stuff in here ... -->

    <auto-detect/>

  </fonts>
</renderer>
```

Then you should invoke the fop command with the `-c` option, e.g.

```
 fop -c path/to/file/fop.xconf myfile.fo myfileout.pdf
```

And it should work properly (assuming the font face can properly render the specific character).